# preg_match , regexp , php , ignore white spaces and new lines

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract **richard123** using php preg_replace but there are a lot of white spaces and new lines and I think because of that my regexp doesn't work .
 The html can be seen here :
http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=vuD3z9ij
 My current preg_match is :

```
$find = "/< tr bgcolor=\"F0F0F0\" valign=\"middle\">< td align=\"left\">< font size=\"-1\">(.*)<\/font><\/td>/";
preg_match_all($find, $res, $matches2);
print_r($matches2);
```

I also tried

```
</td>/s";
```

```
</td>/m";
```

```
</td>/x";
```

but doesn't work either .

Comment: offtopic: Do you really use `font` tags ? Mixed with css ?!!

Comment: If you're going to parse HTML, learn to use an HTML parser. IE: search for PHP DOMDocument or Simple HTML DOM in google + tutorial, and learn.

Comment: offtopic: nc3b ,  the website is not mine... I just parse some info published there

Comment: regarding PHP DOMDocument I understand that it works well only for well formed html documents . Most of the html documents that I need to parse are not well formed at all so that's why I think regexp is more suitable

Comment: It also works with malformed HTML. Use loadHTML instead of loadXML and call libxml_use_internal_errors before so that you don't see the parsing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"!<tr bgcolor=\"F0F0F0\" valign=\"middle\">\\s*<td align=\"left\"><font size=\"-1\">(.+?)</font></td>!"
```